# What happens to orphaned Yarn Child processes?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

Hadoop YARN launches instances of YarnChild in child VM to execute the actual tasks. Those tasks communicate with their ApplicationMaster (AM) through the umbilical interface.

My question is what happens if AM dies and Resource Manager(RM) fails to bring it up (say, due to some code defect in AM)? In such a case, the children tasks would (a) note the absence of AM due to heartbeat and then, (b) go to RM to get new AM location, which in this case they will not get. So, what happens to these orphaned tasks? I have a scenario where I would like to terminate them. Is that the default behavior and does their NodeManager (NM) terminate them?

Answer (score 0):

From Hadoop -Definitive Guide, Chapter 6, Failures, Failures in yarn

> After a crash, a new resource manager instance is brought up(by
>   admin), and it recovers from the saved state. The state consists of
>   node managers in system, as well as running applications. Here tasks
>   are not part of resource managers state, as they are managed by
>   application.

Also, it is said that the resource manager is designed to be able to recover from crashes.

Comment: RM crash and recovery is ok, but I was wanting to know what happens in case of AM crash? RM will bring it back up (ideally) and then tasks would know of new location of AM. However, in case of AM not coming up at all, what would happen to orphaned tasks?

Comment: Lets see, if anyone has answer. This [might](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-556) have some information, leading to that.

Answer (score 0):

All child task related to that particular application master would be on halt state. Hadoop admin should either restart the application master or kill it. NodeManager doesn't terminate the failed Application Master.

If you want to kill a application then you can use `yarn application -kill application_id` command to kill the application. It will kill all running and queued jobs under the application.

If you want to kill a task in YARN then you can use `hadoop job -kill-task <task-id>` to kill a particular task in YARN

Comment: I'd agree about halt state because children are no longer able to send heartbeats to AM. How long would such tasks stay in halted state? Is there a setting after which these tasks are terminated in case the corresponding AM does not come back up?

Comment: If the Application Master fails twice it will not be tried again the entire job will fail. The maximum attempt is 2(default) and this configuration is controlled by `mapreduce.am.max-attempts`

Comment: But suppose if you have configured `job.recovery.enable` in your cluster and resource manager has already started a new instance of failed application master then old application mater will be considered as fail.

Comment: And is there a _Configuration_ to set the time interval after which orphan children would be terminated in case mapreduce.am.max-attempts to start AM fail? Or is their termination immediate?

Comment: There is not time interval configuration for it. If the application master fails after 2 attempts. All child process also get fail and entire job is considered as fail.